# How to modify breaks and lables within ggproto?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

I have a `ggplot` function (`ggproto`) to generate a manhattan plot. The code works, but I can't get my function to correctly position the breaks and labels on the x-axis. So I  would really appreciate help on: How I can get my function to plot the axis that I want. Is it possible within the `stat_manhattan` function or would it be better to code an extra `scale_x_chr`(or so) function? Many thanks in advance! P.S hope my question is clear.

This is the code for the function:

```r
StatManhattan <- ggplot2::ggproto("StatManhattan", 
                                  ggplot2::Stat,
                                  # set up parameters, e.g. unpack from list
                                  setup_params = function(data, params) {
                                    params
                                  },
                                  # Compute group is the most granular component to be called
                                  compute_group = function(data, scales, params, col_chrom) {
                                    message("My param has value ", scales)
                                    
                                    data_1 <- data %>% 
                                      dplyr::arrange(chr, pos) %>% 
                                      dplyr::transmute(x = cumsum(as.numeric(pos)), 
                                                       y,
                                                       chr)
                                    
                                    data_2 <- data_1 %>% 
                                      dplyr::distinct(chr) %>% 
                                      dplyr::mutate(colour = rep(col_chrom, length.out = dplyr::n()))
                                    
                                    # the final df
                                    data_1 %>% 
                                      dplyr::left_join(data_2, by = "chr") %>% 
                                      as.data.frame()
                                    
                                  },
                                  required_aes = c("y", "pos", "chr"),
                                  default_aes = aes(y = stat(y), 
                                                    x = stat(x), 
                                                    colour = stat(colour), 
                                                    size = 0.2)
)


stat_manhattan <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "point",
                           position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = FALSE, 
                           inherit.aes = TRUE, col_chrom = c("magenta2", "grey60"),
                           ...) {
  ggplot2::layer(
    stat = StatManhattan, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, 
                  col_chrom = col_chrom,
                  ...)
  )
}
```

This can generate the desired plot, but the x-axis has continuous labels - which is not what I want.

```r
# test data
test_data <- tibble(chr = rep(1:3, each = 1000), 
                    bp  = c(sort(sample.int(1e6, 1000)), 
                            sort(sample.int(1e6, 1000)),
                            sort(sample.int(1e6, 1000))),
                    p = runif(3000, min=0, max=1))

# plotting the test data
ggplot(test_data)+aes(chr = chr, pos = bp, y =-log10(p))+stat_manhattan()
```

[image]

What I want to achieve is something like this, where the chromosome (`chr`) numbers are centered on the x-axis.

```r
axisdf = test_data %>% 
  mutate(bp_cum = cumsum(as.numeric(bp))) %>% 
  group_by(chr) %>% 
  summarize(center=( max(bp_cum) + min(bp_cum) ) / 2 )

test_data %>% 
  mutate(bp_cum = cumsum(as.numeric(bp))) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x=bp_cum, y=-log10(p), colour = as.character(chr))) +
  geom_point() +
  # custom X axis:
  scale_x_continuous(label = axisdf$chr, breaks= axisdf$center )
```

[image]

Comment: I think it goes against the grammar of graphics to entwine layers and scales this way. They are normally very separable. It might be possible if you're willing to offend that grammar, but it would be a bit counterintuitive I suppose.

Comment: Adding on to teunbrand's point, if you just want the *appearance* of different axis breaks / labels, you can take a page from `geom_sf()`, which sneakily includes `coord_sf()` whenever it is called, and do the same in your `stat_manhattan()` function. It should be simpler & cleaner than tinkering inside `StatManhattan`.